# Can zfs/zpool be setup in an LVM formatted disk

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, zfs

I have Ubuntu 14.04 setup with LVM on a 500GB disk on my laptop. I want to setup/playaround with zfs/zpool. What is the best approach for this without losing my data

Answer (score 4):

**Given that you just want to "play around" with ZFS,** the easiest option is probably a file-backed pool. An alternative would be creating one or more logical volumes inside the LVM and use those.

One of the beauties of ZFS is that you can give it just about anything that can store data in a random I/O capable form, and it will "just work". **In production environments, you generally want to give ZFS a whole disk** (or several whole disks) and let it handle partitioning etc., but for trying things out and getting a feel for how ZFS works, a file-backed pool is almost always perfectly adequate.

In fact, I sometimes recommend having a file-backed pool resembling the full storage layout readily available, because it allows you to safely test various changes and observe the results before committing to them. Mistakes in altering ZFS pools can be costly.

To create a file-backed pool, first create a set of files of appropriate size. I'll be creating a four-device raidz1 pool where each device (file) is 2 GB, so:

```
sudo mkdir /.zfs
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/.zfs/disk1 bs=1M count=2048
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/.zfs/disk2 bs=1M count=2048
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/.zfs/disk3 bs=1M count=2048
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/.zfs/disk4 bs=1M count=2048
sudo chmod 0700 /.zfs
```

This gives us four files in /.zfs, named disk1 through disk4 respectively. Each file will be 2 GiB in size, which when accounting for raidz1 overhead gives us a usable storage capacity of a little under 6 GiB (in raidz1, one of the devices is used for parity data so not available for use).

Then create the pool (`tank` is the customary example name for a ZFS pool):

```
sudo zpool create tank raidz /.zfs/disk1 /.zfs/disk2 /.zfs/disk3 /.zfs/disk4
```

What this says is to create a pool named `tank` using defaults, and set up one vdev in that pool with the four files we just created. The pool will automatically be imported once created, and its root file system will be mounted at `/tank`. You can observe the result using `sudo zpool status`, which should print something very similar to:

```
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME             STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank             ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0       ONLINE       0     0     0
        /.zfs/disk1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        /.zfs/disk2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        /.zfs/disk3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        /.zfs/disk4  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

We can confirm the raw size of the pool using `sudo zpool list`:

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  7,94G   120K  7,94G         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

and the used and available storage capacity using `sudo zfs list`:

```
NAME   USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank  74,8K  5,84G  25,4K  /tank
```

Both of those commands have numerous options to control what gets printed and how; see the man page for `zpool` and `zfs`, respectively.

You can now save files into /tank and generally get your hands dirty with ZFS. To export the pool (recommended before shutdown), `sudo zpool export tank` (or `sudo zpool export -a` to export all currently imported pools). To import the pool again, `sudo zpool import -d /.zfs -a` (or replace the `-a` with the name of the pool, `tank`); the `-d /.zfs` may be needed because ZFS doesn't normally look in that directory for devices. You can add these commands to your system startup/shutdown scripts if you want to.

Have fun!